# Which turbulence model: k-epsilon or k-omega?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm modelling a tidal harbour in Ansys Fluent and want to include a turbulence model in my simulation. I want to predict the water movements around a pontoon which is situated in the harbour. Which turbulence model should I use, a $k$-$\varepsilon$ model or a $k$-$\omega$ model?

The harbour is modelled as a rectangular ($120\times 80\times 6$ m LxWxH) box and the water flows in through an entrance channel ($40 \times 10 \times 6$ m). To simulation flow around a pontoon, a rectangular box ($40\times 3\times 5$ m) is placed at the long side of the harbour and water can flow around an underneath the pontoon. Velocities are 0.3 m/s and lower.

Comment: What do you want to predict?

Comment: I've added it to my question above, I want to see the water movements around the pontoon.

Comment: Are you interested then in the forces on the pantoon?  Seems like the free surface and buoyancy of the pantoon would be important.  In any case, the scheme I have seen used the most is in _Mellor, G. L. and T. Yamada, 1982: Developement of a turbulence closure model for geophysical fluid problems, Rev. Geophys. Space Phys., 20, 851-875_.